# PHP - matching a string against best partial match

Tags: php, performance, csv, pattern-matching

I have a CSV file which contains partial (or full, variable length) UK postcodes in the first column, and assorted tariff information in the subsequent columns.

I have a website form which asks users to enter their full UK postcode.

The application then needs to find the best match to their postcode against the CSV file. All characters of the matched record must be in their actual postcode and the best match for this purpose will be the match from the CSV that has the most characters of their postcode in the same order, and has no characters that do not feature in the postcode.

I've toyed with adding this CSV'ed data to a mysql database but I don't think (please correct me if wrong) it would be more efficient.

The CSV file contains different length'ed postcodes to match against.

E.g.

B1 (should be the match for anything starting B1 where there's not a more precise match elsewhere)

```
B13
B12 1NA
```

So the postcode B1 2NB should match the first entry.
B12 1NB should also match the first example.
B13 2PQ would match the 2nd example.

Essentially I need to search the CSV file for the closest match, then load in the full row into an array that can be used for further calculations.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?
Assuming loading the whole CSV into memory is not the best approach?

Comment: db would make it dead easy: `select ... where postcode like '$search%' order by length(postcode) desc`

Comment: use a database table

Comment: It depends... how many rows are in your CSV? what sort of efficiency are you looking for - easy for you to develop? ready to scale to millions of requests per second?

Comment: @Tom - there's just under 1000 rows. 
It's a low use site but I'd like to do it right / fastest response time possible.

Answer (score 1):

With around 1,000 rows and let's say 50-100 bytes of data per row, that's "only" 50k-100k of memory, which is not that much.

PHP op-caching is pretty good, so APC or Zend OpCache will do all the "in memory" caching that you need, as long as your files are PHP, not loading from & parsing a CSV each time.

Whilst a DB is certainly more scalable, the overhead of TCP connections and network latency may not make it the most performant.

I offer up this code sample as a way to implement this *IF* you decide that the in-memory PHP solution is the best for you.

```
<?php

/**
 * Class PostcodeLookup
 *
 * Keeping the lookup data in a PHP file like this means that it will be cached in memory by APC or OpCache
 */
class PostcodeLookup
{

    /**
     * This will contain our lookup data and payload
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $arr_pc = [];

    /**
     * Populate the lookup array on construction
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arr_pc = [
            'M1' => 'test1',
            'M12' => 'test2',
            'M123' => 'test3',
            'G1' => 'test4',
            'G2' => 'test5',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Our public function for running lookups
     *
     * This is here so we normalise the data ONCE and strlen() ONCE
     *
     * @param $str_pc
     * @return bool
     */
    public function run($str_pc)
    {
        $str_normalised = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $str_pc));
        return $this->check($str_normalised, strlen($str_normalised));
    }

    /**
     * Reducing, recursive lookup
     *
     * @param $str_pc
     * @param $int_length
     * @return bool
     */
    private function check($str_pc, $int_length)
    {
        if(isset($this->arr_pc[$str_pc])) {
            return $this->arr_pc[$str_pc];
        }
        return $int_length > 1 ? $this->check(substr($str_pc, 0, -1), --$int_length) : false;
    }
}

// Some example usage
$obj_lookup = new PostcodeLookup();
var_dump($obj_lookup->run('M123'));
var_dump($obj_lookup->run('M1'));
var_dump($obj_lookup->run('M19999'));
var_dump($obj_lookup->run('G2'));
```

Comment: It's a nice approach - but in this case the CSV files may be updated/replaced regularly. Uploading them is just about within my clients' tech limits, but copying / formatting them into PHP less so. 

Thanks though.

Comment: Well, you can still memcache the parsed CSV array. Then just update it when the file mtime changes. That way you're still avoiding a full load & parse